# Linux kernel section names

Tags: linker, kernel, ld

Why do some linux kernel section names use a single . and others use two
For example .data..page_aligned and .data..init_task vs .data.unlikely and .data.once

Does the number of . have a specific meaning

Thanks

I have read the ld and kernel documentation and not found any information

Answer (score 0):

Section name `.data..init_task` consists from 3 parts:

1. Prefix `.data`.
2. Delimiter `.`.
3. Name of the subsection `.init_task`.

Since the name of the subsection starts with dot, the section name contains the sequence of two dots.

---

The section name `.data.unlikely` consists from 3 parts too, but the name of the subsection - `unlikely` - is not started with dot.